# JSON property null check

Tags: java, json

```
{
  "amount": {
    "value": "",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
}
```

How do i check if "value" property is present and it's value is null or not?

`getAmount().getValue() != null && getAmount().getValue() == null` ???

Comment: How are you reading the JSON? What have you tried so far? Also, what do you think `value != null && value == null` will return? How can an object be both non-null and null at the same time?

Comment: that's what i don't know...on how to check...

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("{\"amount\": {\"value\": \"\",\"currency\": \"USD\" }}");

    if(json.amount.value != null && json.amount.value !=""){ 
        //value is not null
    }else{
      // value is null
}
```

Note  : import org.json.simple.JSONObject;